# Displaying angular JSON array on frontend

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have my data in the following format,

```
        var data = [{"time":1,"description":"Here lies 1","cost":"10"},{"time":2,"description":"Here lies 2","cost":"20"},{"time":3,"description":"Here lies 3","cost":"10"},{"time":4,"description":"Here lies 3","cost":"10"}]
```

which I am trying to render using

```
<div class="container">
                <h3 class="text-center">Welcome to our scheduling page. Please follow the instructions to add an event to my calendar.</h3> 
             <div ng-app="TimeSlot">
                <div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="TimeSlotController as calendar" >
                     <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 timeblock" ng-repeat="slots in calendar.timeslot" ng-click="">
                        <h3 class="event-type-name">{{slots.time}} Hour Appointment</h3>
                        <div class="description mts">{{slots.description}}</div>
                        <div class="cost">{{slots.cost }}</div>
                     </div>
                </div>

             </div> 

        </div>
```

and

```
var timeslots = data;

var app =   angular.module('TimeSlot', []);

app.controller("TimeSlotController", function($scope) {

    this.timeslot = timeslots;

});
```

The divs are repeating according to the number of objects but the values are not getting inserted into the view, why is that so ?

This might look a repeat of my previous question but it's not exactly the same, sorry if I am repeating though.

Comment: Cannot reproduce neither with [old angular](http://jsfiddle.net/wz4u2f6f/) nor [new](http://jsfiddle.net/wz4u2f6f/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1qwo1wcu/

Comment: You don't have [angular](https://angularjs.org/) included in that fiddle. `angular-animate.js` is an addon for `angular.js`, it is not a replacement for it. You need *both*

Comment: sorry you are right, it does work in the new version as well; its funny how im not able to do it locally

Comment: I am using handelbars, does it help in anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is wrong..   try this

```
app.controller("TimeSlotController", function($scope) {

    $scope.timeslot = timeslots;

});



<div ng-app="TimeSlot">
     <div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="TimeSlotController" >
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 timeblock" ng-repeat="slots in timeslot" ng-click="">
            <h3 class="event-type-name">{{slots.time}} Hour Appointment</h3>
            <div class="description mts">{{slots.description}}</div>
            <div class="cost">{{slots.cost }}</div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with handlebars, so I simply used the interpolate provider to fix it.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider